# use of 'with' after comma

Tags: meaning

> *Pursuing this analogy further might help us to understand how voices change over a person’s life, **with** some growing older with the voice-hearer, others frozen in time.*

What does *with* refer to in that sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to *how voices change*.

Another example would be: *Answers given here will receive evaluations, with some being upvoted, others being downvoted*. Here it lists the possible options for the evaluations.

In your sentence, some voices change by growing older, other voices will be frozen in time, and the *with* introduces these possibilities.

Comment: thank you! Is there any source including some information or example about such use of "with" as in the sentence above?